# How to add share feature in My Notes app for Android?

Tags: java, android

I have an app for Android, and it's for writing notes and save it. I want to add **"Share"** feature to the app, if the user hold press the note in the **MainActivity**, it will shows **"Share"** option, if the user press that option, it will share the title and the body of the note **(or just the body of the note)**. I used the below code, but nothing shows if I chose an app to share the content to it **(Ex.: Messaging app)**.

```
...
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ...
        case R.id.share:
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_with)));
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the shared text within the code:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO SHARE);
```

If you want to retrieve the text from R.id.share (e.g. EditText),

```
EditText share = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.share);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share.getText().toString());
```

Comment: But I need to share the text inside the note, not any text!

Comment: What do you mean by note?An EditText field?

Comment: I need to share a note (Title and body or just the body), the note contain some text, I need to share that text to an app. Just like that. See my app on Google Play for more information: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotes

Comment: If note is a user-defined class, you should create a function like getValue() to retrieve the text from the note then